# Crash when creating image folder

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android app that takes a screenshot and saves it on the App image folder, this is the code I use to create the folder and save the screenshot:

```
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Porte3D");    
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        // Write your image name here
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
               out.flush();
               out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

I'm testing this with 2 devices, a samsung galaxy S2 and a moto G, on the S2 the folder gets created and the image is stored correctly but the moto G crashes with the following error:

```
10-27 09:09:41.422: A/libc(12069): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002f25 (code=-6), thread 12435 (Thread-62263)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in order to work on every device?

Comment: You have to be sure that ExternalStorage is available before using it

Comment: That's not the error, the ExternalStorage is available on my Moto G

Comment: one more thing   sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
This is deprecated as from KitKat,eventhough its not the reason for you crash, i just ponted out,paste yr full crash log

Comment: have you given permission for using external storage in manifest?

Comment: yes, @GeorgeThomas the crashlog I get it's just the line I posted, I don't get any other error

Comment: if its working with the jelly bean version and not with the kitkat version then its the problem of the broadcast you are calling

Comment: Ok i'll try to change it, can you tell me what's the right method to call now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to check existence of the directory then create it. Replace

```
myDir.mkdirs();
```

by

```
if (! myDir.exists()){
        if (! myDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyAPp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Another problem in your code is, in KitKat your code will not work(That is why it is not working in moto g)

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
  // File f = new File("folderPATH", "fileName");
   Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(myDir);
   mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
   sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
 } 
 else {
       sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" +Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "FOLDER_TO_REFRESH")));
    }
```

And your complete code will be like this

```
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Porte3D");    
    if (! myDir.exists()){
      if (! myDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d("MyAPp", "failed to create directory");
        return null;
       }
    }
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    // Write your image name here
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
      File f = new File(myDir, fname);
      Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
      mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
      sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
     } 
   else {
     sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
   }
```

Comment: Using this code the app doesn't crash but on the Moto G i can't see the screenshots on the folder, I don't have a variable to pass FolderPath and FileName, should I create them?

Comment: @Signo edited my code. Try and let me know if you get further issues

Comment: No still the gallery doesn't show up.. Thanks a lot for the help anyways :)

Comment: Yes now it's working I must've changed something for error, I was going crazy trying to solve this :) THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

I dunno wheather its the actual problem with your code, but its worth a try

```
   MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
      }
 });
```

Make sure you have correct permission for reading and writing to external store
and pass the file name that you want to scan

Answer (score 0):

sure it ll help u man

```
   public class FileCache {

    /** The cache dir. */
    private File cacheDir;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new file cache.
     *
     * @param context the context
     */
    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the file.
     *
     * @param url the url
     * @return the file
     */
    public File getFile(String url){
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    /**
     * Clear.
     */
    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```